# Switching between gesture recognizers depending on direction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following setup:

- `TableView`
- `ScrollView`

  - `ContainerView`

`ScrollView` lies on top of `TableView` and **completely covers it**, but they are siblings.

`ScrollView` scrolls left and right (paging enabled) and `TableView` scrolls up and down.

I want to scroll the right thing depending on scroll direction.

Tried subclassing `ScrollView` and overriding `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`:

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

    isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    if let gR = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer{
        let vel = gR.velocity(in: gR.view)

        let x = fabs(vel.y) < fabs(vel.x)

        isUserInteractionEnabled = x
        return x   
    }
    return true
}
```

That approach didn't work out properly.

I also tried

```
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tableView.panGestureRecognizer)
```

but that didn't work either because it removes `panGestureRecognizer` from `TableView`.